# how to alter table using JPQL in spring Boot application

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jpql

> I want to alter a table using JPQL but it is not possible to alter the
> table how can I alter the table using JPQL,I want to remove studentId
> form Teacher table .
> Here is my query to alter the Teacher Table but it is not Working

```
/**Drop studentId column  from the teacher table*/
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("update Teacher t  drop t.studentId")
    fun drpStudentID():Long
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below application property and from Entity(model) class you have to remove corresponding column of Entity.

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: I already use this line of code in my application.properties file